# Can't change language in WP dashboard

Tags: wordpress

I have two WordPress websites and I want to change to another language in the WordPress dashboard, but it did not take effect.

Here are the screenshots of them:

1. First website displayed these items right after I clicked “Save Changes” in language option in General settings.

   [image: First website error.]
2. On the second website the language is set in English but the dashboard still displays content with the previous language.

   [image: Second website where English is set but the content is still the previous language.]

Comment: Looks like a Question for [wordpress.se](wordpress.stackexchange.com)?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because its a valid question but I believe it belongs on the [WordPress-specific Stack Exchange site](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com).